# What functions have vanishing boundary conditions for $0^{th}$ and $1^{st}$ order derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

What (non-trivial) functions satisfy $f(a)=f(b)=f'(a)=f'(b)=0$? I am working on some undergrad research and would like to understand this a bit more.

#### Context

I am investigating a differential equation of the form $y^{(4)}+ky=0$, where $k$ is a parameter.  Basically an Sturm-Liouville problem of 4th order.

Comment: Note that, since your linear ODE has constant coefficients, you can assume that your interval of interest is $[0,1]$ rather than $[a,b]$.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Presumably, you'll need to learn LaTeX anyway to type up the results of your research.... Let me know if my answer below missed the point of your question, or if something should be added there.

Answer (score 1):

Any function of the form $f(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^2 g(x)$, where $g$ is differentiable, satisfies those boundary conditions. That's a pretty big family.

Also, any linear space $V$ of differentiable function such that $\dim V\ge 5$ contains nontrivial functions that satisfy the conditions. Indeed, the zero set of a linear functional has codimension $1$, and the common zero set of $4$ linear functionals has codimension $4$.

For example, the space of functions of the form $\sum_{k=1}^5 c_k e^{\lambda_k x}$ contains some such functions.

**However** the space of solutions of $y^{(4)}+ky=0$ is only $4$-dimensional. So we should expect that normally, there will not be any nontrivial solutions. Of course, we might get lucky: when $k$ is a specific constant (depending on $b-a$), there will be solutions. You can dig into this by writing down the general solution $y(x) = \sum_{k=1}^4 c_4 e^{\lambda_k x}$ and plugging this into the boundary conditions. Some $\lambda_k$ are complex here; trigonometric functions can be used to deal with those.

Comment: Thank you.  should I be able to solve for these $\lambda_k$'s ?

Comment: @user3427062 Yes, plug $y=e^{\lambda x}$ into the ODE and solve. You may want to read a chapter of ODE textbook on linear equations with constant coefficients.... By the way, I used $k$ as an index without noticing you already used it for the coefficient. Hope this wasn't too confusing.